# Iterate through multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two multiprocessing threads, one adds items to a queue, the other needs to iterate through the current queue. How do I do that iteration? Or alternatively, how do I convert the current queue to a list to iterate?

Some pseudocode:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
thequeue = mp.Queue()
def func1():
    global thequeue
    while True:
        item = readstream()
        if item not None:
            thequeue.put(item)
def func2():
    while True:
        for item in thequeue:    # This only works for Lists, how to do this for queues?
            if item == "hi":
                print(item)
main():
    mp.Process(target=func1).start()
    mp.Process(target=func2).start()
```

Comment: This is not a minimal working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The question lacks a lot of detail, first being - how did you create threads in Python and what is the queue class you're using?

Comment: Added more code @VictorSergienko

Comment: This, I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157739/how-to-iterate-through-a-python-queue-queue-with-a-for-loop-instead-of-a-while-l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Queue` doesn't support iteration directly, because `for` looping over a container is expected to not modify the container. Such nondestructive iteration is both impossible to support in the `multiprocessing.Queue` implementation, and a fundamentally inappropriate operation for the use cases `multiprocessing.Queue` was designed for.

Consumers should use `get`, which retrieves and removes items from the queue:

```
def func2():
    while True:
        item = thequeue.get()
        if item == 'hi':
            print(item)
```

If you prefer the code structure of a `for` loop, you can use two-argument `iter` as shown in Sraw's answer, but you'll **still remove items from the queue** that way. It is not possible to iterate over a `multiprocessing.Queue` without removing items.

Comment: How is it "fundamentally inappropriate"? As the other answer shows, it's trivial to build and use a generator for it.

Comment: @pmos: Iterating over a container with a standard `for` loop is nondestructive, but `multiprocessing.Queue` cannot support nondestructive iteration, and nondestructive iteration would run counter to the use of `multiprocessing.Queue` as a message-passing synchronization mechanism.

Comment: You can use `iter` to construct an iterator fed from the queue and then iterate over that, but you cannot iterate over a queue directly, and `multiprocessing.Queue` will almost certainly never support direct iteration.

Comment: Also, that's not a generator. Generators are a specific type of iterator, which is not the type that two-argument `iter` creates.

Comment: Fair enough on this not being a generator, but you say yourself that iteration with `for` is only nondestructive for *containers* - destructive iteration over non-containers with `for` is totally idiomatic and commonplace Python: e.g. iterating over a file object or standard stream (yielding lines if it's opened in text mode), generators, ...

Answer (score 14):

If you want to write your code in terms of a `for` loop, you can use the [two-argument form of `iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
def func2():
    for item in iter(thequeue.get, None):
        # do what you want
```

And to stop this process, you just need to put a `None` into `thequeue`, or you can make your own signal to stop if `None` is common in your case.

Note that unlike a normal `for` loop, this will **remove items from the queue**, just like calling `get` manually would. There is no way to iterate through an inter-process queue without removing items.

Comment: Note that this might not work if there are multiple processes pushing into the queue. it would be difficult to figure out which one of the producers must push in None. In such cases, @user2357112 's answer, though uglier, is easier to implement

Comment: @gokul_uf You misunderstood. Join all producers in main thread and then put `None` in. Producers don't need to care about it.