# TypeError: argument of type 'Object' is not iterable

Tags: python, amqp, qpid

I've written what I thought was a simple python script to search through several lines of output and match (i.e. "grep") on a specific string. Listing all queues without the pattern match is simple enough:

```
from qmf.console import Session
sess = Session()
broker = sess.addBroker("amqp://guest/guest@localhost")
queues = sess.getObjects(_class="queue", _package="org.apache.qpid.broker")
for q in queues:
  print (q)
```

Running the script produces the following output (truncated):

```
pmena@myhost=> python ./queue_stuff.py
org.apache.qpid.broker:queue[0-1-1-0-62] 0-1-1-0-3:queue01
org.apache.qpid.broker:queue[0-1-1-0-55] 0-1-1-0-3:queue02
org.apache.qpid.broker:queue[0-1-1-0-63] 0-1-1-0-3:queue03
org.apache.qpid.broker:queue[0-1-1-0-51] 0-1-1-0-3:queue04
.
.
org.apache.qpid.broker:queue[0-1-1-0-51] 0-1-1-0-3:queue99
```

However when I add an "if" statement to match on a particular string, like so:

```
from qmf.console import Session
sess = Session()
broker = sess.addBroker("amqp://guest/guest@localhost")
queues = sess.getObjects(_class="queue", _package="org.apache.qpid.broker")
for q in queues:
  if 'queue37' in q:
    print (q)
```

I get the following error:

```
pmena@myhost=> python ./queue_stuff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./queue_stuff.py", line 6, in <module>
    if 'queue37' in q:
TypeError: argument of type 'Object' is not iterable
```

I feel like this is a simple python syntax issue, but wasn't able to glean the resolution from other posts.

Comment: `q` appears to be a class that just has a `__repr__` method to display as a string. Try `if 'queue37' in repr(q):` or `if 'queue37' in str(q):`. The object may have an id value that you can check too, which would likely be faster.

Comment: @Carcigenicate typed faster ... `getObjects` returns *objects*, not strings.  When you asked whether a string was in the object, Python decided you were trying to do an element check on something iterable -- hence the error message.  If you're confused, print out the type and structure of `q`.  Better yet, check the documentation on these objects, so that you can extract the needed attribute to compare against *that*.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? Specifcially, for the queue object? Also, it would help to explain *specifically what problem you are trying to solve* with this `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Queue class does not have an *iter* method like you might suspect. That method needs to be defined for a class for `for i in object:`  to work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157739/how-to-iterate-through-a-python-queue-queue-with-a-for-loop-instead-of-a-while-l) goes over a variety of workarounds that people have used, so you can see which one best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `q` is Object instead of a string.
You should check

```
for q in queues:
    print (type(q))
```

if q is object you cannot use `if 'queue37' in q`

Comment: It looks like @PAUL MENA's code is intending to loop through an object and not a string. The problem is that the Queue object doesn't have an __iter__ method like people may expect it to.

Comment: Exactly! Q is not a string rather it is some class object.